# Android notification will not open my activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a foreground service whose notification should open an activity, only I can't get it to work...

Here is how I set up my notification:

```
private void setupRunningNotification() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this);
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
    notificationBuilder.setContentText(getString(R.string.running_notification));
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    notificationBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MIN);

    runningNotification = notificationBuilder.build();
}
```

**Edit:**

I simply used the wrong function.

Answer (score 1):

`PendingIntent.getService` (as the name suggests) is used to run a `Service`. If you want to launch an `Activity`, then you need to make use of [`PendingIntent.getActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivity(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int))

Answer (score 1):

By using:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

You're setting an intent that will start a service, according to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getService(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)).
For starting an activity you should call getActivity:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```